# JavaScript frame resize script

Tags: javascript

I have this script for a iframe on my site but the iframe doesn't get smaller when the content inside the iframe is small. He only resizes the iframe if the content inside the iframe is bigger. How can I fix this so when the content inside the iframe is smaller also resize the iframe to the small content?

Sorry I find this very hard to explain

```
function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For Chrome, it won't work in localhost mode. Upload to a real web server.

For Firefox, the iframe content won't show up in localhost mode.

For IE/Safari, it will work on localhost.

Basically, your codes are OK.

P.S.: Remove the space before .body.

Comment: I anwered this when I have not enough score to comment. I now can comment. Sorry.